# Do I need a knowledge of programming to set a blog on wordpress?

Tags: free, blog

I tried before but faced some difficulties. Do I need to study some coding?

Comment: Hi Oma, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Please have a look at the [help] and the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what Stack Exchange is about and what is on an off topic on this site. To be honest, I'm afraid your question doesn't really fit our on-topic description. Nevertheless, thanks for joining us!

Answer (score 2):

I should be possible to setup a WordPress site using a template for the layout and adding some plugins for extra functionality.

If you bought hosting and a domain, it's very likely they have an express WordPress setup function, that sets up a basic site where you only have to enter a little bit of information on the site.

You can check out this How To, it takes you through the basics.
http://thenuschool.com/create-a-wordpress-website-just-15-min-no-coding-needed/

Although a little bit of HTML and CSS understanding is preferable, it's not needed.

I will suggest a site like Codecademy for an easy to understand intro to HTML and CSS. And if you like it, also do the PHP one, it will also help you with WordPress, since that is the language it is build in.

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html